# printing mysql data using php

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to print the data form mysql using the following code.
Am I missing something?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("myDB");
$res=mysql_query("select * from myTABLE");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "$row[id]";
?>
```

Comment: Use `echo $row['id'];` instead of  `"$row[id]";` and complete while loop missing `}`.

Comment: Yes, first of all you lack the ending `}` character that will terminate the `while` loop. Then you should really update to something like `pdo` or `mysqli` since the `mysql` extension is deprecated. You should also enable error reporting to get a descriptive error message i.e put this at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: just add error_reporting(E_ALL); in the starting of the file, just after the php tag, it will print the error in your code, and help you debug it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing curly bracket. And put `id` into quotation marks:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("myDB");
$res=mysql_query("select * from myTABLE");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo $row['id'];
}
?>
```

I recommend using `mysqli`. `mysql` extension is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) on echo,

This part shows you how to print arrays:

```
// You can also use arrays
$baz = array("value" => "foo");

echo "this is {$baz['value']} !"; // this is foo !
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate your responses. I am able to make it work now.
I am trying to make the code more specific and secure.

I tried joining two tables, using this and it won't print the id from main (m.id) and category_name on c.category_name table.

```
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT m.id, c.category_name FROM `main` AS m INNER JOIN `categories` AS c ON m.category_id=c.id");
```

The code below works

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * from main");
```

Regarding connecting to the db via a separate file. This doesn't work. And no errors are being display on the php even after adding error_reporting.

```
require_once('../../../hide/dbconn.php');
```

instead of using below

```
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("myDB");
```